# PHP XML Parse data

Tags: php, xml

I have never used XML before and am trying to loop through the XML and display all the display names in the 'A Team'. The code I am using is outputting 10 zeros and not the names.

The code I am using is attached below along with the feed.

Any assistance is much appreciated!

feed: https://apn.apcentiaservices.co.uk/ContactXML/agentfeed?organisation=se724de89ca150f

```html
 <?php
  
  
  $url = 'https://apn.apcentiaservices.co.uk/ContactXML/agentfeed?organisation=se724de89ca150f';
  $html = "";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
 $title = $xml->organisation['APN']->brand['AllStar Psychics']->pool['A Team']->agent[$i]->display-name;
 
 echo $title;
        
}
echo $html;
  

 
  ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried `...gent[$i]->{'display-name'};` ?

Comment: Hi, just tired and that doesn't return anything at all :(

Comment: The attribute `name`, not `value`, goes in the `[]`.

Comment: are you referring to the $i in the agent attribute? I tried making that change with no result either: $title = $xml->organisation->brand->pool->agent->display-name;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might getthe basics you asked for. Not sure if it's what you want. I'm not that good at xpath.

```
$mydata = $xml->xpath('/organisation/brand/pool[@name="A Team"]//display-name');

foreach($mydata as $key=>$value){
  echo('Name:' . $value .'<br>');
}
```